# Removing m2e.projectLocation from pom.properties

Tags: maven

Maven generates a `pom.properties` file inside META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId} than contains the version, groupId and artifactId. But I have also found out that there is a `m2e.projectLocation` property with the value as the project path. I want to remove it since I don't want others to know the project path.
Is there any way to remove that property from the file?
Note: It seems like it has something to do with eclipse.

Comment: Where is that property `m2e.projectLocation` defined in the `pom.xml` ? Have you build your project on plain command line?

Comment: @khmarbaise There is no `m2e.projectLocation` defined in the `pom.xml` I think its generated automatically. I have built my project using the shade plugin `mvn package shade:shade` but it seems like its also happening on `mvn install`

Comment: First `mvn package` should do everything if not your build not configured correctly. Using `mvn install` will not change anything until you define something your build... Please post a pom file or a link to a project on github or alike... Furthermore the question is why you do `mvn install`?

Comment: I'm pretty new to maven. I have been using the shade plugin with `mvn install shade:shade` for a bit and it seemed like it worked fine. Here is a link to the pom file: https://pastebin.com/cdvbqGR3

Comment: It would be better to post the pom file within the post here on SO instead of external resources ... (better formatting etc.) The issue that you have defined the execution blocks of maven-shade-plugin within pluginManagement instead outside of it... that will make it more convenient like `mvn package`... also run on plain command line and take a look into the jar files...

Answer (score 0):

The `m2e.projectLocation` property in `pom.properties` is not generated by Maven per-se; it is generated by Eclipse's `m2e` plugin.

There is a bug report about this behaviour, apparently you (and I) are not the only one(s) who oppose it:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=528786

There is no way I can think of to remove just that field; however, you can have Maven avoid generating `pom.properties` altogether by configuring `maven-archiver-plugin` and setting `addMavenDescriptor` as `false`:

https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/